# Can I make the Podcasts App play my unplayed podcasts in chronological order?

Tags: ios, podcasts, podcasts.app

The new Podcasts app is pretty swell. I'm particularly fond of the 'Unplayed Episodes' button that generates a playlist of all my unplayed podcast episodes, on which I can just hit 'Play' and let a half a dozen episodes of different podcasts just run in order, without having to actually edit or manage a playlist.

But there's one problem: They play newest first. **Is there any way to change this playback order so that I can hear my oldest unplayed podcasts first?**

Comment: Hi, there are a number of Podcasts apps. (Podcasts Assistant, Podcast Player Pro, etc). Which app are you using? If you are using Apple's Podcast Assistant, here is a comprehensive review - http://www.arnnet.com.au/article/429243/app_day_podcasts_by_apple/?fp=4&fpid=56736 The app will improve but this early version leaves a lot to be desired. Maybe try another app?

Comment: @DavidDelMonte I'm sorry, I thought I was being clear through my use of capitalization and the tag. I'm specifically referring to the new app **Podcasts**, which is made by Apple and is now on the App Store.

Comment: oops. I adjusted my comment and our wires crossed.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

The combined **Unplayed Episodes** playlist has no settings and defaults to newest first.

As of version 1.01, you can only sort **individual subscriptions** by oldest first.

Even if you go through the trouble of changing each individual subscription preference to oldest first, Podcasts app will still keep the **Unplayed Episodes** playlist sorted to newest first.

Answer (score 0):

This post is the first result when I google this exact problem, so hopefully this will help you if you've also reached this page after screaming "why does it insist on playing episode 331 after episode 4? Just play episode 5!" There is hope (I have iOS 11.2.6 and Podcasts 3.4):

Step 1: Click on the square of the podcast title that you want to play chronologically, then select the "..." of the episode that appears at the top of the screen:

[image: Click the periods to the right of the top episode name]

Step 2: Choose "Settings" in the menu that appears:

[image: The menu contains "unsubscribe", "delete from library", "settings", "play next", and "share" options.]

Step 3: Select "play in sequential order":

[image: Playback options are "sequential order", "most recent first", "only keep the most recent episodes", and "custom settings".]

The podcast will now play the series as desired.

Caution! If you click the "..." of the *playing* episode, rather than the episode at the top of the podcast title's screen, you will not see the playback settings:

[image: The playing episode's "..." contains only "add to library", "save episode", "play next", and "share episode" options.]

Comment: This works for a single podcast; my question was about doing this for episodes of multiple podcasts, I.e. every episode of every podcast that came out on Tuesday, followed by every episode of every podcast that came out on Wednesday, etc.